# Why does IntelliJ IDEA run button invoke maven run and not the default Application

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea

Why does intellij IDEA run button invoke maven run and not the default Application run and I can't find any way to change it.

[image: run button]

[image: run button dropdown]

[image: mvn run]

On my other Intellij IDEA setup, the run button would invoke the regular Application run.

Is there a setting in IDEA to change how the run button behaves?

I'm using Intellij IDEA 2016.2.3 on Windows

Comment: in eclipse next to the run button there is a dropdown menu which lets you select several classes to run. maybe you have something similar in intellij

Comment: I should add that this is the run button that appears next to the main() method.  The screenshot is in the question but it doesn't show as an embedded image.

Comment: Attach a screenshot of the popup you see when you click on the Run icon in the left gutter. What are Before Launch steps of the Application Run/Debug configuration?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I have added the dropdown screenshot

Comment: What about the [before launch steps](http://i.imgur.com/IZiQg9r.png)? How do you know that it runs Maven? Could it be that you have [enabled the option to start Maven goal before run](http://i.imgur.com/IFzWlQy.png)?

Comment: You can right click and run any class with a main method.  IntelliJ will create a run profile for you.  Learn how to use the IDE properly.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I've added another screenshot showing it runs maven.

Comment: Still no answers to the questions regarding before launch steps and before run settings for Maven goals.

Comment: @duffymo I understand that it does.  Though I'm expecting it to create an Application profile but it creates a mvn profile instead.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using IntelliJ 2017 EAP.  Never seen it done what you are describing.  You're doing something else wrong.

Comment: @duffymo perhaps something is wrong, though I'm interested to know what it is.

Comment: Can't tell based on what you posted.  I have high confidence that the problem is not with IntelliJ.  Edit your run configurations and remove every profile you see.  Then return to the class you want to run and ask IntelliJ to run it.  There won't be any Maven involved if that class has a main method.

Comment: It doesn't look like Maven configuration. Maven would have the [gear icon](http://i.imgur.com/6AM7UFF.png). Did you install any plugins?

Comment: @CrazyCoder It was the "Maven Runner plugin". I removed it and the run icon is working normally.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the Maven Runner plugin that caused the issue.

[Maven Runner plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHABV.png)

Remove it and the run button is launching Application run as expected.

Thanks to @CrazyCoder for the plugin hint.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible that you have the option `Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven` checked in your `Settings` - simple uncheck it :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can choose which project you wish to run - press shift+alt+F10 and make your choice.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/running-applications.html

Comment: It is not that I can't run the program.  I'm wondering why the default behavior for the run button in the gutter is different on one of my IntelliJ IDEA install and there is seemingly no way to alter it.  It is kind of an annoyance because I have to create a run profile each time I need to run something.